# plotting list object using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running some simulations that I was wondering to plot the outcomes in a beautiful ggplot, but it seems that ggplot can't deal with list objects. Does anyone knows how to paste the results into ggplot chart?

```
   N <- 8619170         
   nn <- c(1000, 1200, 3000)
   p <- .27     
   nsim <- 100

    phat <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(nn)) {
    n <- nn[i]
    x <- rhyper(nsim, N * p, N * (1 - p), n)
    phat[[i]] <- x / n
    }
```

## Ugly solution:

```
    names(phat) <- paste("n=", nn)
    stripchart(phat, method="stack")
    abline(v=p, lty=2, col="red")
```

Comment: Once you have your list in a format that ggplot2 likes, see some of the examples at ?geom_dotplot

Comment: I think the question is a real question, i.e., how to plot data given in lists using ggplot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ggplot2 need a data.frame as a source data. So you need to :

1. transform the data with reshape2 (or plyr or many other tools)
2. plot using qplot or ggplot

   e.g

   ```
    ## transform data
    require(reshape2)
    h <- do.call(cbind, phat)
    h.melt <- melt(h)

    ## rename variables so they look nicer on plots
    names(h.melt) <- c("test","N","value")     

    ## stripchart (not shown)
    qplot(data = h.melt, x = value,y = N,color=N)+geom_point()

    ## histogram (not shown)    
    ggplot(h.melt,aes(x=value,fill=N))+geom_histogram()+facet_grid(N~.)

    ## dotplot with rug (not shown)
    ggplot(h.melt,aes(x=value,fill=N))+geom_dotplot()+facet_grid(N~.)+geom_rug()  

    ##density plot with rug (shown below)
    ggplot(h.melt,aes(x=value,fill=N))+geom_density()+facet_grid(N~.)+geom_rug()
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Just to riff off this answer a little, we might name the columns so they look better in the plot and try histograms, density plots, dotplots, and maybe add rugs.  Things like:
`names(h.melt) <- c("test","N","value")
ggplot(h.melt,aes(x=value,fill=N))+geom_histogram()+facet_grid(N~.)+geom_rug()
ggplot(h.melt,aes(x=value,fill=N))+geom_dotplot()+facet_grid(N~.)+geom_rug()
ggplot(h.melt,aes(x=value,fill=N))+geom_density()+facet_grid(N~.)+geom_rug()`

Answer (score 3):

The best I could do following your clue is:

```
qplot(data = h.melt, x = value,y = Var2)+ geom_point(shape=1, size=5)
```

but still it doesn't reflect the probabilities; the points should be stacked as a sort of histogram to reflect the probabilities.

A different approach is using the density function, but it can messy things if I have many samples categories to plot out.

```
ggplot(h.melt, aes(x=value, fill=Var2)) + geom_density(alpha=.5, position="identity")
```